# How to use sine, cosine, log function in android studio

Tags: java, android, math, android-studio, trigonometry

I made a simple calculator as my first android program, now I wanted to add `trigonometry`, `log`, etc functions to it.
In `C` we have to include `math library` to do so, I can't seem to figure out how you do that in `java`, in `android studio`.
Because  when I write `a=sin(b);` it doesn't recognize `sin`.
So can someone tell me include keyword and library name to write which will include these functions.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_sin.htm) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sin, cos, log and a bunch of other stuff is included in the [Math class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html).

You would need to use it like `Math.sin(angleInRadians);`

Answer (score 0):

Use it with Math library. Math.cos(...